# Angular JS executing function $timer within $scope receives TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, angularjs-scope

Why is that when using `$timeout` in Angular JS that is inside function like the following, works fine.

```
var mytimeout = $timeout(function(){
    console.log("MyTimeout Executed");
},2000);
mytimeout.then(
    function() {
        console.log( "mytimeout resolved!", Date.now() );
    },
    function() {
        console.log( "mytimeout rejected!", Date.now() );
    }
);
```

but when I use `$timer` with a function inside `$scope` it does not work, like this:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(){
   console.log("MyTimeout Executed");
}; 

var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.myFunction(),2000);
mytimeout.then(
    function() {
        console.log( "mytimeout resolved!", Date.now() );
    },
    function() {
        console.log( "mytimeout rejected!", Date.now() );
    }
);
```

and recieve this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:14015:28
    at completeOutstandingRequest (http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:4301:10)
    at http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:4602:7 angular.js?body=1:9779
(anonymous function) angular.js?body=1:9779
(anonymous function) angular.js?body=1:7217
(anonymous function) angular.js?body=1:14018
completeOutstandingRequest angular.js?body=1:4301
(anonymous function) angular.js?body=1:4602
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.myFunction(),2000);
```

This is your problem. Remove the `()` from the `myFunction()`. You need to pass a function reference, not call the function and take the result (which in this case would be `undefined`) and then pass *that* to $timeout.