# Angular and ngTagsInput - Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I'm not able to make this work, every time I type 3 chars I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at core.min.js?v=1494950519:37874
    at processQueue (core.min.js?v=1494950519:14634)
    at core.min.js?v=1494950519:14650
    at Scope.$eval (core.min.js?v=1494950519:15916)
    at Scope.$digest (core.min.js?v=1494950519:15727)
    at Scope.$apply (core.min.js?v=1494950519:16024)
    at core.min.js?v=1494950519:17791
    at completeOutstandingRequest (core.min.js?v=1494950519:5490)
    at core.min.js?v=1494950519:5762
```

This is in my controller:

```
 $scope.loadItems = function (query) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        defer.resolve([
            { text: 'just' },
            { text: 'some' },
            { text: 'cool' },
            { text: 'tags' }
        ]);
        return defer.promise;
    };
```

and this is in my html:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags">
     <auto-complete source="loadItems($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Can't figured put what's wrong, any idea?
If I remove the `auto-complete` it works.

Comment: do you have a response interceptor?

Comment: It do not even do a request if I see the network tab

Comment: If you could provide a jsfiddle would be very great

Comment: here is the fiddle based on your code which works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/NJwm5/16/, I guess some parts of your app, specially a response interceptor is messing up.

Comment: I was able to inspect the error and it fails here: ` return logFn.apply(console, args);`

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847430/angular-js-executing-function-timer-within-scope-receives-typeerror maybe it helps or try searching for 'completeOutstandingRequest'